# phalcon get enum values

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

I'm working with database with a lot of columns with 'enum' and 'set' type. My point is to get values of column in Phalcon controller. I found some snippets, but nothing in Phalcon and when I tried to execute them it seems that Phalcon have some problems.

```
public function getEnumValues(){
    $sql  = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM profiles LIKE 'eyes_color'";

    $query = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query($sql, $this->getDI());
    $result = $query->execute();

    return $result;
}
```

Returns:

> Syntax error, unexpected token IDENTIFIER(SHOW), near to ' COLUMNS FROM profiles LIKE 'eyes_color'', when parsing: SHOW COLUMNS FROM profiles LIKE 'eyes_color'

Approach 2:

```
public function getEnumValues(){
    $sql = "SELECT COLUMN_TYPE FROM COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'profiles' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'hair_color'";

    $query = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query($sql, $this->getDI());
    $result = $query->execute();

    return $result;
}
```

Returns:

> Model 'COLUMNS' could not be loaded

I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 3):

This is working version for your needs:

```
$config = $this->getDI()->get('config');
$pdo    = new \Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql([
    "host"     => $config->database->host,
    "username" => $config->database->username,
    "password" => $config->database->password,
    "dbname"   => $config->database->dbname,
]);
$sql = "
    SELECT TRIM(TRAILING ')' FROM SUBSTRING(COLUMN_TYPE,6)) AS enum_list
    FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='my_db_name'
        AND TABLE_NAME='my_table_name'
        AND COLUMN_NAME='my_column_name'
";
$result    = $pdo->query($sql)->fetch();
$enumArray = array();
if (!empty($result['enum_list'])) {
    $enumArray = explode(',', $result['enum_list']);
    foreach ($enumArray as &$value) {
        $value = trim($value, "'");
    }
}
echo "<pre>"; var_dump($enumArray); die;
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you get what you want from the columnMap function in the model?

```
$model = new Profile();
$columns = $model->columnMap();
```

This will return an array of all columns. Possible create another similar function to just return the columns you want? Perhaps what you're trying to achieve is more involved.

BTW I got the same error using the modelManager.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but it doesn't resolve the problem. The point is to get enum values dynamically, so it really doesn't matter where I will do it. The problem is how to do it.